# How do I find out how many workers is my disk.frame using?

Tags: disk.frame

I am using the `disk.frame` package and I wanted to know how many workers is `disk.frame` using to perform the operations? I looked through `disk.frame` documentation and can't find such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disk.frame` uses the `future` package to manage the workers. So we can simply use `future::nbrOfWorkers()` to find out.